# Delphi Indy 10 HTTP Client curious behaviour with .NET IIS Application

Tags: delphi, indy10, idhttp

I've come across a curious  problem with Indy 10 IdHTTP client.

I have written an application which connects to a .NET HTTPS web site hosted on IIS 8.5, does a GET, extracts the Viewstate etc, and then does a POST to the login form, passing back the viewstate and the login parameters.

My app needs to do this repeatedly, as a form of heartbeat, every 30 minutes.

I have found that if I drop a TIdHTTP, TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and TIdCookieManager on a form, and connect them up, and set their various parameters, then I can do a GET followed by a POST and it all works fine.

However, if without closing the form, I do it again, then the response I get back from the server on the second GET is either null, or a small number of bytes, so my logic to extract the Viewstate fails, and the subsequent POST contains incorrect data, causing a 500 error from the server.

Here's a log extract to illustrate:

```
2018-07-14 14:03:49 - Service Started
2018-07-14 14:04:48 - Configuration loaded
2018-07-14 14:04:48 - Service Executed
2018-07-14 14:04:48 - sending GET request
2018-07-14 14:04:49 - Get response = HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2018-07-14 14:04:49 - sending POST request
2018-07-14 14:04:49 - __EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&    __VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJODIyMTE4ODg2D2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYOAgMPDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGRkAgUPDxYCHwBoZGQCCQ8PFgIfAGhkFgJmDxYCHgtfIUl0ZW1Db3VudGZkAgsPPCsABQEADxYCHwBoZGQCDQ8WAh8AaGQCEw9kFgICAQ8PFgIfAGdkFgICAQ9kFgICAQ9kFgJmD2QWAgIBD2QWAmYPZBYCAg0PEA8WAh4HQ2hlY2tlZGhkZGRkAhUPFgIeBFRleHQFHCYjMTY5OyAyMDE4IFN0YW5zdGVkIEV4cHJlc3NkGAIFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBSVjdGwwMCRDcE1haW4kTG9naW4xJExvZ2luMSRSZW1lbWJlck1lBSJjdGwwMCRDcE1haW4kTG9naW4xJExvZ2luTXVsdGlWaWV3Dw9kZmQMaw6DwiWb7Dsi6X%2BgNBnXKQcEqw%3D%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAVTevg71fLSFTbKbOw%2F93SHsrUT%2BQjdDS15mCJiqiynuBdZ2pvBHooH4AJuhXVIPc1mZjzeA4EOClAyNHHGNchy3%2FmkJIoBKJzRpOCUtULeTi1Kr73J8c%2B%2BfFWSSK7ysEo5hJkL&ctl00$CpMain$Login1$Login1$UserName=--------&ctl00$CpMain$Login1$Login1$Password=---------&ctl00$CpMain$Login1$Login1$LoginButton=Log%2Bin
2018-07-14 14:04:49 - Post response = HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2018-07-14 14:05:50 - Configuration loaded
2018-07-14 14:05:50 - Service Executed
2018-07-14 14:05:50 - sending GET request
2018-07-14 14:05:50 - Get response = HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2018-07-14 14:05:50 - sending POST request
2018-07-14 14:05:50 - __EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=&__EVENTVALIDATION=&ctl00$CpMain$Login1$Login1$UserName=------&ctl00$CpMain$Login1$Login1$Password=--------&ctl00$CpMain$Login1$Login1$LoginButton=Log%2Bin
2018-07-14 14:05:50 - Post request failed
2018-07-14 14:05:50 - Post response = HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

I found that the second GET request gets this response back from the server, instead of the correct document:

```
2018-07-14 14:27:45 - Service Executed
2018-07-14 14:27:45 - sending GET request
2018-07-14 14:27:45 - ?
2018-07-14 14:27:45 - Get response = HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

So it still returns 200 OK but no content.

I tried all sorts to work out why this was happening, I thought I'd inadvertently set a range on my request or something, but everything checked out. I checked that all the variables, MemoryStreams, StringLists etc that I used were reset between calls to GET.

So in desperation I considered the possibility that somehow, the TIdHTTP component was somehow not making the same request, or was persisting the data of the first response.

So I removed the components from the form, and recreated them at run time in my DoGetRequest and DoPostRequest procedures, like this:

```
procedure TBackofficeHeartbeat.DoGetRequest;
var
  GetResponse: string;
begin
     LogActivity('sending GET request');
     IdHTTP1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
     IdSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
     IdSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
     IdSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
     IdCookie := TIdCookieManager.Create(nil);
     IdHTTP1.CookieManager := IdCookie;
     IdHTTP1.IOHandler := IdSSL;
     IdHTTP1.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
     IdHTTP1.Request.Connection := 'close';
     IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
     try
          try
               GetResponse := idHTTP1.Get(cfgLiveURL);
          except
               LogActivity('Get request failed');
          end;
          //if cfgDebug then LogActivity(GetResponse);
          html := GetResponse;
          LogActivity('Get response = ' + IdHTTP1.ResponseText);
      finally
           IdCookie.Free;
           IdSSL.Free;
           IdHTTP1.Free;
      end;
end;
```

Strangely, having done this, there's no longer a problem with making subsequent calls to GET and POST, they always work.

This suggests that somehow there is a persistence of data which causes a difference in the second GET request on a TIdHTTP component which isn't destroyed and re-created between calls.

Can anyone suggest what might be the cause of this? Could it be, for instance, that the session isn't closed, and therefore the server thinks you are doing a refresh, not a complete request?

Looking in the IIS logs, and using Fiddler, I can't find any difference between the first and second GET request and yet the server doesn't respond the same.

I've got my application working, so this isn't a big problem. just curious if Remy or anybody else can explain it.

EDIT:

On Remy's suggestion I added a TIdLogFile, and from the output of that it's obvious there are differences in the first and second calls to GET.

```
Sent 15/07/2018 10:07:37: GET / HTTP/1.1<EOL>
Host:backoffice.stanstedexpress.com<EOL>
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0<EOL><EOL>
```

And after doing the POST:

```
Sent 15/07/2018 10:07:57: GET / HTTP/1.1<EOL>
Connection: Keep-Alive<EOL>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8<EOL>
Host: backoffice.stanstedexpress.com<EOL>
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<EOL>
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate, identity<EOL>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0<EOL>
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=w1b5tdn4uks5qn4zxthybq2f<EOL><EOL>
```

This would explain the different server responses, I think.

Comment: When reusing the same `TIdHTTP` object for multiple requests, the only data that `TIdHTTP` persists between requests is cookies and authentication credentials. I suggest you attach one of Indy's `TIdLog...` components to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property so that you can log the actual HTTP requests that `TIdHTTP` is sending.

Comment: Thanks for replying Remy, I did as you suggested, see above.